# External monitor connects then disconnects rapidly then connects again

Tags: windows-7, laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a month old acer laptop (Aspire VN7-591G) which ran Windows 10, now runs Windows 7. (Had to downgrade to be able to use some old programs, will upgrade back again when finished. Windows 10 is great!)

Both when I was running 10 and now 7 I had the laptop configured to extend its desktop to my HDMI-connected external monitor which is an LG 19LE5300.

This monitor has two HDMI ports, one goes to the laptop and the other one goes to a PS4.

Whenever I switch the input on the TV to the PS4's HDMI, the laptop seems to connect and disconnect the TV continuously every 2-3 seconds. It's like I were plugging the HDMI cable, then unplugging it, plugging it back in, for eternity.

It'll stop when I either unplug the HDMI from the laptop, or change the input on the TV back to the laptop.

What can I do?

I've tried:

- Multiple OSs (Win 7 and Win 10)
- Pretty sure I had a different driver on windows 10 than here on windows 7.
- Both fresh installs, no weird apps or bloatware messing with either OS.

Haven't tried a different cable now that I think about it, will try and report back!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, if somebody encounters this problem

This monitor has two HDMI ports, one of them (HDMI 1) is labeled HDMI-DVI, the other one (HDMI 2), just HDMI.

My nvidia Geforce GTX 960M does not apparently like HDMI-DVI ports (That lable is odd since you can in theory transform hdmi into dvi and viceversa(losing audio from hdmi tho))

The ps4 doesnt mind this weird hdmi-dvi port so I just swapped both hdmi cables at the TV.